# How to extract host name from a tcp/udp packet?

Tags: android, dns, vpn, packet, packet-sniffers

I have a `tcp` packet. From the tcp header, I can get the destination IP address. My goal is to find the hostname for the destination.

I tried to do reverse dns look up using the code below.

```
try {
    hostname = InetAddress.getByName(myIp).getHostName();
    Log.w("Host for ", myIp + " is " + hostname) ;
    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
        Log.w("Unknown Host for ", myIp);
}
```

The above code gives the output as:

> W/Host for: 172.217.3.33 is iad23s57-in-f1.1e100.net
>
> W/Host for: 216.58.217.142 is iad23s43-in-f14.1e100.net . . .

I want the hostname as the name of the website. example. youtube.com, stackoverflow.com etc.

I tried to use `MiniDNS` library for this.

```
ResolverResult<A> result = DnssecResolverApi.INSTANCE.resolve(hostname, A.class);

if (!result.wasSuccessful()) {
    DnsMessage.RESPONSE_CODE responseCode = result.getResponseCode();
    // Perform error handling.
    Log.d(TAG, “ Result Not successful");
    return;
}

if (!result.isAuthenticData()) {
    // Response was not secured with DNSSEC.
    Log.d(TAG, ”Result Not authentic");
    return;
}


Set<A> answers = result.getAnswers();
for (A a : answers) {
    InetAddress inetAddress = a.getInetAddress();
    // Do someting with the InetAddress, e.g. connect to.
    Log.d(TAG, InetAddress.toString());
}
```

The above code gives the following error:

> Access denied finding property "net.dns1"

I am able to parse the `tcp/udp` packet to get the `tcp/udp header` and get the destination address. Is there any way to get the hostname from the packet other than the destination ip?

Comment: Why do you believe all hosts have reverse names? It is not mandatory so many requests from an IP will not yield an hostname. There are no hostnames in TCP/IP packets, only IP addresses. Except if you analyze the portion part, like if it is HTTP then you may have an Host: header and hence a "destination" hostname. However filtering on things like that at the TCP/IP level is not easy and borders to impossible with HTTPS.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I tried MiniDNS library to get the actual host name from the canonical host name I got from the first code, but it worked only once and then showed Access Denied error. Online documentation shows that it doesn't work on Android 9 onwards. But it shows the same error for previous versions as well. I did get the result once for all the queries but then it stopped working after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, you received correct hostname. To understand, you needs to know how DNS is working and how it my be used to distribute traffic to local area hosts.

DNS has [multiple types of records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types). One of particular interests are:

- `A Record`, that stores hostname to IPv4 mapping.
- `PTR Record`, that does the reverse
  mapping.

Lets go though an **example** and query for google.com IP:

```sh
$ dig +noall +answer google.com any

google.com.     38795   IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     299 IN  A   172.217.16.14
google.com.     58  IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 281257231 900 900 1800 60
google.com.     277 IN  AAAA    2a00:1450:401b:804::200e
google.com.     38795   IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     38795   IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     38795   IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
```

Records marked with A are `A records`.
Note that results may vary in time and location. DNS load balancing may be applied. One hostname can be resolved to many possible other IP addresses or subdomains.

Lets do a reverse lookup, try to get host from an IPv4 address:

```sh
$ dig +noall +answer -x 172.217.16.14

14.16.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 85118 IN    PTR waw02s13-in-f14.1e100.net.
14.16.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 85118 IN    PTR mil02s06-in-f14.1e100.net.
```

`PTR Records` that were returned point to two different hostnames. This is example of [anycast address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast). Both servers have same IP address. None of those resolves back to google.com domain.

It is essentially one to manny mapping, google.com host delegates handling of requests to many different hosts. But DNS don't track the original/primary host.

You possible could do lookups for [SOA record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOA_record).

```sh
$ dig SOA mil02s06-in-f14.1e100.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> SOA mil02s06-in-f14.1e100.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28298
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mil02s06-in-f14.1e100.net. IN  SOA

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
1e100.net.      60  IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 281257231 900 900 1800 60

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 62.179.1.60#53(62.179.1.60)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 20 14:25:16 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

So you know it belongs to google. However, I don't think that Android SDK has a way to do SOA query.